# Understanding the rate of change in titration curves

Tags: acid-base, analytical-chemistry

As I am looking at titration curves, a few things stand out. For now, I have a two part question:

1. When titrating an acid with a base, for instance, the pH rises more or less abruptly around the equivalence point. Does this have to do with the logarithmic nature of pH? In other words, is this caused by the fact that the number of particles involved in the jump from e.g. a pH of 2 to one of 3 is several orders of magnitude than the number of particles involved in the jump from 6 to 7?
2. When a weak acid is titrated, the rise to the equivalence point is a lot more shallow. Does this happen because of Le Chatelier's principle? That is to say, as the base is titrating the acid, some of the acid that has not dissociated will dissociate in an attempt to restore equilibrium. This should retard the titration to some degree. Is that the case?

Comment: Hi Sadiq. Consider splitting this into multiple questions, so they can better be answered. Also, please use a more precise and clear question title. The current one is too "literary" for the technical nature of the question.

Comment: OK just a moment

Comment: I have changed the title but if the question needs to be split, I'll allow a moderator to do that—I kind of think that someone who will be able to answer one part will be able to answer the other as they are closely related

Comment: Hi Sadiq, it's okay to split your own question up (just edit out the second part and paste it into a new question).  I agree with @CHM that splitting it would probably be to your benefit, but it's your choice.

Comment: I just don't want to spam up the board, you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer from a member of Chemical Forums who seems to have been quite useful to other posters in the past given his or her "karma" would appear to confirm that the shape of titration curves owes in part to their logarithmic nature:

http://www.chemicalforums.com/index.php?topic=6140.0